# Can I close the iPhone browser using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iphone, safari

In the iPhone is there a way I can use JavaScript to close the browser and return to the home screen? After the last page a wizard I am calling out to another iPhone app (ex: maps) and I do NOT what the user to come back to the browser screen when they are done. My backup plan is to have a "Complete" page but that is not the best experience for the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have confirmed with apple this is not possible in iPhone OS 2.2 and before.

I have tried each of these good suggestions but, they will not close the browser on the iPhone.

Comment: And what about iOS versions after 2.2? What would be working code there?

Answer (score 0):

Knowing Apple, this may not be possible with JavaScript. Have you tried anything yet? If not, try one of these guys out:

```
javascript:self.close();
window.close();
```

EDIT: I found this thru google, this may bypass the confirmation box, but I don't think it works with the modern browsers anymore:

```
window.opener='x';
window.close();
```

I just checked, doesn't look like it will work (IE7 box pops up, FF3 does nothing, Opera 9.61 doesnt have a prompt box at all).

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [Anders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262273/can-i-close-the-iphone-browser-using-javascript#262356): `window.close()` will do what you want. According to the [Window](http://www.devguru.com/Technologies/ecmascript/quickref/window.html) doc page, if you try and close an window not opened via javascript, the user will be prompted to confirm.